# Чем git diff --cached отличается от git diff --staged?

Tags: git, git-diff

Создаю файл readme.txt с содержимым "hello world!", и индексирую его

```
git add readme.txt
```

Изменяю содержимое файла на "hello git!", выполняю команду `git status`

```
git status -s
AM readme.txt
```

При этом команды `git diff --cached` и `git diff --staged` дают один и тот же результат

```
diff --git a/readme.txt b/readme.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a042389
--- /dev/null
+++ b/readme.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello git!
```

В чем различие этих двух параметров? Если различие есть, как создать ситуацию, когда оно проявится?

Comment: Такие варианты появляются потому, что развитие git в общем-то нелинейно и эволюционно. Сначала появился какой-то один вариантов, потом для единообразия параметров добавили второй, а старый оставили для обратной совместимости.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

согласно [документации по git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> --staged is a synonym of --cached

перевод:

> --staged — это синоним --cached